# Delete policy using Microsoft Graph Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, policy

I want to delete conditional access policy from Microsoft Graph Powershell.

I found this to do from Graph api

> DELETE
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies/%7Bid%7D)

But how to find the command for this in Microsoft Graph Powershell.

PS: I connected to Graph from Powershell with `Connect-MgGraph`

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

Initially I have an conditional policy like **`Require MFA to user administrator`** in my portal.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Commands:**
I tried with below commands and I removed a conditional policy successfully.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'Policy.ReadWrite.ConditionalAccess', 'Policy.Read.All'
Get-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy
$conditionalAccessPolicyId="Id"
Remove-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy -ConditionalAccessPolicyId $conditionalAccessPolicyId
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Remove-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy` cmdlet to remove the conditional access policy.

```
Remove-MgIdentityConditionalAccessPolicy
      -ConditionalAccessPolicyId <String>
      [-IfMatch <String>]
      [-PassThru]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/remove-mgidentityconditionalaccesspolicy?view=graph-powershell-1.0) to know more about the cmdlet and also the accepted input values to those parameters.

Here is the [MG graph PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/?view=graph-powershell-1.0) cmdlets documentation.